# POO (Java) - Como conseguir que se muestre mi dato del ArrayList?

Tags: java, poo, arraylist

Tengo este código en mi Main:

```
System.out.println(c.mostrarDetalles());
```

Cuando lo imprimo por pantalla sale esto(y sus variantes de números para cada arrayList guardado):

```
Empresa :[Act7.Empresas@6acbcfc0, Act7.Empresas@5f184fc6]
```

Este código viene desde un arraylist almacenado en un objeto llamado empresas
que tiene lo siguiente:

```
public class Empresas {

private String empresa;
    //constructor empresa
    public Empresas(String empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }

    public String getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresa(String empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }
}
```

a su vez tengo otro objeto llamado Campanya que aparte de crear otras variables para este objeto coge la variable empresa de Empresas(objeto)

```
public class Campanya {

    private ArrayList<Empresas> empresa;

    //constructor con mas variables yo enseño la que es afectada solo
    public Campanya(ArrayList<Empresas> empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }

    //imprimo la empresa
    public String mostrarDetalles() {
        return "Empresa :"+ this.empresa;
    }
}
```

La coge como arrayList o almenos eso me sugeria el programa ya que en el main consigo el dato de cada empresa a través de un arraylist.
Para que os hagais una idea del main.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    //arrayList que cogen mas datos de las empresas y campañas

    ArrayList <Empresas> empresa = new ArrayList<Empresas>();
    ArrayList <Campanya> campanyaDet = new ArrayList<Campanya>();


    //adds a campanyas y empresas
    //a continuacion se imprime los arrays
    for(Campanya c: campanyaDet) {  
        System.out.println(c.mostrarDetalles());
    }
}
```

Como consigo que se vea mi dato en vez de esos números ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea un método `toString()` en la clase Empresas, algo como:

```
public class Empresas {

    //// Aquí va la implementación actual de la clase ////

    public String toString() {
        return this.empresa;
    }
}
```

El método `toString()` en Java se llama automáticamente cuando se necesita convertir una instancia de una clase cualqueira a un String, como en la expresión: `"Empresa :"+ this.empresa;`

Adicionalmente a añadir el `toString()` en `Empresas`, puedes modificar el `mostrarDetalles()` de la siguiente manera:

```
public String mostrarDetalles() {
    return "Empresas :"+ String.join(", ", this.empresa);
}
```

Ten en cuenta que dentro de Campanya tienes un lista de empresas, no una individual, el [String.join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) convierte un objeto iterable como un ArrayList en un String, añadiendo un separador.

Comment: Hola Roberto!! siguen apareciendo los numeros aunque cree el toString, en verdad mi metodo mostrarDestalles hace lo mismo que el toString pero con diferente nombre

Comment: Eso es extraño, debería salir el nombre de la empresa, ¿ lo añadiste a la clase `Empresas` ? De todas formas, añado otra solución alternativa, más robusta.

Comment: lo añadi en la clase campaña que es el que lo imprime junto con otros detalles de la campaña

Comment: he tratado de añadir el String.join pero me pide que cambie los arrayList que tengo guardados a char[] algo asi ponia y por lo tanto en mi codigo da error, necesito los arrayList

Comment: No, no, debes añadirlo donde te dije en `Empresas` verás como funciona

Comment: Olvidate de momento del String.join, con el toString() en Empresas debe funcionarte

Comment: Eso era el toString en Empresas!! al fin se muestra muchisimas gracias!!! Al estar tratanto con ArrayList tambien es un poco lioso

Answer (score 0):

Sobrescribe el método `toString()` en tu clase `Empresas`, el cual devuelve en un `String`, la información que desees sobre la empresa:

Ya tienes un código que envía la información de la empresa (pero se encuentra en la clase `Campanya`), solo tendrías que cambiar el nombre para que se sobrescriba el método correspondiente.

```
public String mostrarDetalles() {
    return "Empresa :"+ this.empresa;
}
```

Debería ser:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Empresa :"+ this.empresa;
    }
```

También puedes acceder a un solo objeto con:

```
    System.out.println(c.get(0)); //0 en este caso es el índice.
```